# Calculating right triangle using random points in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

I am trying to create right triangles using random coordinates in turtle. Sometimes my code works, while other times the hypotenuse of my triangle goes in the wrong direction. I have spent hours trying to figure out what it causing the inconsistency.

There are several shapes within the code. However, only the `RightTriangle` class is giving me issues so I have removed the others.

If anyone is able to figure out how I can resolve the issues I am having I would be extremely grateful.

```
from turtle import Turtle
import random
from math import sqrt, degrees, asin, acos, atan 

class Shape():

    turtle = Turtle()


class RightTriangle(Shape):

    def __init__(self, A, B):
        self.A = A
        self.B = B

    def draw(self):
        a = (self.B[0] - (self.A[0]))
        b = (self.B[1] - (self.A[1]))
        c = (sqrt((self.B[0] - self.A[0])**2 + (self.B[1] - self.A[1])**2))
        angleA = degrees(atan(a/b))
        angleB = degrees(atan(b/a))

        Shape.turtle.penup()
        Shape.turtle.setposition(self.A)
        Shape.turtle.pendown()
        Shape.turtle.forward(a)
        Shape.turtle.right(90)
        Shape.turtle.forward(b)
        Shape.turtle.right(180-angleA)
        Shape.turtle.forward(c)
        Shape.turtle.penup()


def random_shapes(count):

    def random_point():
        return (random.randint(-200,200), random.randint(-200,200))

    shapes = []

    for i in range(1, count+1):
            shapes += [RightTriangle(random_point(), random_point())]

    return shapes

def main():

    shapes = random_shapes(15)
    for s in shapes:
        s.draw()

    input ('Hit <enter> key to end.')
    input ('Have a nice day!')

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

With your existing code the lengths of the edges can be negative which changes the meaning of your "forward" movements and "right" turns. Use absolute values when calculating lengths:

```
a = abs(self.B[0] - (self.A[0]))
b = abs(self.B[1] - (self.A[1]))
```

Note that `c` is always positive.

As a side note, you don't need the `angleB` variable in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `a` and `b` to represent `dx` and `dy`, and always starting at `A`.  Think about whether it can be right to **always** do `right(90)` (hint, it cannot).  If `B` is vertically above `A` you will go down instead of up (if you adopt the abs mentioned by Selcuk).

Comment: True, there is also an edge case where `A` and `B` are the same point.

Comment: Or even the same x or y coordinate (leading to `ZeroDivision`)

Answer (score 0):

One really simply way to do this is to just point back towards point A in the turtle code. You can do this with

```
Shape.turtle.setheading(Shape.turtle.towards(self.A))
```

in the place of

```
Shape.turtle.right(180-angleA)
```

This is definitely the least truly mathematical way to solve this but it does work quite nicely.